# How to send email if any changes made in audit logs in SQL Server 2014 Developer edition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am creating a project for practice and following is the requirement: whenever anyone makes any change in SQL Server procedures, then the entry for change goes into the Audit Log. And we need to notify the list of audit logs, if any changes made.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I am creating any sp related to ddl or dml, these entries are going into Audit logs but i am not able to send notification via mail.

Comment: Can you post the code that you are using to send the email? And how are you inserting the data into audit log? Using any custom triggers or are you using extended events?

Comment: For sending mail, i am using sql server wizard. I am able to audit the logs but not able to send the mail for that specific audit.

Comment: If you are using the wizard, how do you know when a stored procedure is changed? Your question is not entirely clear. And what exactly do you mean by auditing the logs?

Comment: I want to make the tool in which any changes make in table,stored procedure,view etc or at server level, then logs will generate in Audit file. Now i want that if any changes happen in audit file so i should be notified via email using Sql server DBmail. This is the requirement.